# Apache Flink: How to make some action after the job is finished?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to do one action after the flink job is finished (make some change in DB). I want to do it in the same flink application with no luck.
I found that there is JobStatusListener that is notified in ExecutionGraph about changed state but I cannot find how I can get this ExecutionGraph to register my listener.
I've tried to completely replace ExecutionGraph in my project (yes, bad approach but...) but as soon as it is runtime library it is not called at all in distributed mode, only in local run.

I have next flink application in short:

```
DataSource.output(RichOutputFormat.class)

ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment().execute()
```

Can please anybody help?

Comment: Hi Cunuu, could you find out how to do this?

Comment: Hi! No, we had no time to investigate it.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer!